# Listview - losing selected items after scroll down

Tags: android, listview

I'm changing the background when some item is selected in my listview, but every time that I scroll down, I'm losing the selected items

**selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```

**adapter**

```
holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    boolean selected = v.isSelected();
    v.setSelected(!selected);
  }
});
```

How I can keep the background state?

Comment: Please post your full adapter class

Comment: Adapter reuses it's views when you scroll. Read about it, there is plenty of questions and answers about this on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your views are being recycled. You need to keep track of the selected views elsewhere (like a list of Integers, where you keep the position of the selected views).

Then, in your adapter, in getView, you set the selected stated based on whether your list contains the position or not.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ...
     view.setSelected(mSelected.contains(position));
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use listView selection instead:

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setItemChecked(itemPosition, true);
```

Or you should call `view.setSelected` in your adapter getView every time. Cause the selected state is lost after view is recycled.